# How to resolve "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. " in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, stm32, background-color, disassembly

I use Eclipse-2022-06-R in ubuntu 20.04.4 to debug stm32. I would like to change Ruler background color of Disassembly page. When I click Apply, Problem Occurred dialog comes out. It says "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Error notifying a preference change listener. Check the log for details." How to solve this error. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewXzn.png)

The .log file in the workspace .metadata directory contains:

```
!SESSION 2022-06-22 10:23:51.271 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.24.0.I20220607-0700
java.version=17.0.3
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=zh_CN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.embedcpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.embedcpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2022-06-22 10:24:11.769
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed:
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:113)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:99)
      at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.disassembly.provisional.DisassemblyRulerColumn.getBaselineBias(DisassemblyRulerColumn.java:935)
      at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.disassembly.provisional.DisassemblyRulerColumn.doPaint(DisassemblyRulerColumn.java:763)
      at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.disassembly.provisional.DisassemblyRulerColumn.doubleBufferPaint(DisassemblyRulerColumn.java:697)
      at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.disassembly.provisional.DisassemblyRulerColumn.lambda$1(DisassemblyRulerColumn.java:606)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5794)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1555)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1538)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_draw(Control.java:3882)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.gtk_draw(Scrollable.java:365)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_draw(Composite.java:496)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.gtk_draw(Canvas.java:174)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2409)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6832)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6114)
      at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk3.GTK3.gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1552)
      at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk3.GTK3.gtk_main_iteration_do(Native Method)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4474)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. We can't help until we see the details.

Comment: Looks like a bug of Eclipse CDT. [Make sure it has reported here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT). The [error occurs here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/debug/internal/ui/disassembly/provisional/DisassemblyRulerColumn.java#n935). Did you also changed some fonts?

Comment: No, I didn't change fonts.

Comment: You might mentioned this in the bug report, as the bug occurs due to an assertion about font metrics (`Assert.isTrue(widgetBaseline >= fontBaseline);`).

Comment: I think I find the solution. If I chose the language to 中文（简体）at the begining of ubuntu system installation, the problem occurs. If I chose the language to English at the begining of ubuntu system installation, the problem disappears.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1853111/?srch=opcodes#msg_1853111

Comment: Please make sure it has been reported to Eclipse, best with a patch.

Comment: I reported this bug to Eclipse as Bug 580248. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=580248

Comment: Thanks! Please feel free to add an self-answer to help others.